# My answer is different from answer sheet - At what time will the stone hit the ground?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This should be a very simple problem, but my answer is different from the answer sheet. The answer sheet says a) is correct, but mine is b).
To solve this problem, simply let $s(t)=0$, then I got $t=0$ or $5$. So I choose 5 seconds, which is answer b), but the answer sheet is a), which is 5 minutes. Am I wrong? If I'm wrong, where is the problem?

> At precisely 10:59:57 AM, a stone is thrown directly upwards from the ground with an initial velocity of $80$ feet per second. The height of the stone is given by $s(t)=-16t^2+80t$. At what time will the stone hit the ground?

$$a) 11:04:57 $$
$$b) 11:00:02 $$

Comment: The question really has no answer at all as written since units are missing completely from this expression for $s(t)$.  If you have other information about units, that must be important.

Comment: maybe $t$ is minutes really? Is that written somewhere or did you copy the question textually?

Comment: The standard units are M.K.S. So $s$ is in meters, $t$ is in seconds. The fact that the problem did not state any unit for the time means the default time unit applies. So the answer must be 5 sec and your answer (B) is correct.

Comment: @Brick: Not completely. The initial velocity is given in feet per **second**, and the same coefficient of $80$ in the equation shows that $t$ is also in seconds. Not to mention that  $16$ for half the gravity is also true in feet per **second** squared only.

Comment: @brick Sorry but you're slightly wrong. It's with the general function $s(t)=-16t^2+80t$. We can determine that the units for $s(t)$ is feet and $t$ is in seconds not minutes, this is due to the fact that $s(t)$ is a relation of distance as $\triangle x(t) = vt+\frac {at^2}{2}$. As we were given the initial velocity as feet/sec  or $v=80 f/s$, it follows that the distance $s(t)$ is in feet and $t$ is in seconds. as such the answer is $b)$.

Comment: The problem appears to have come from here:  http://uca.edu/actm/files/2013/01/2014-ACTM-ALG-II-State.pdf (problem 7). But a "revised" version (according to the url) is quite different:  http://uca.edu/actm/files/2013/01/Revised-ACTM-Regional-Algebra-II-Exam-2014.pdf

Comment: @zipirovich The fact that you can infer units does not make it any less wrong that they were dropped.

Answer (score 5):

It's safe to assume that $t$ is in seconds (because the term $16t^2$ has the coefficient $16$, which is one half of [free fall acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) 
measured in $\mbox{ft/s}^2$).

We solve
$$
80t - 16t^2 = 0
$$
with the additional condition $t>0$. This gives
$$
t = 5\,\mbox{seconds.}
$$
So answer (B) is correct.

Comment: Why must it be 5 sec and not 5 min?

Comment: Time is in seconds and height is in feet - because $g=32\mbox{ft/s}^2$ is the free fall acceleration (aka standard gravity) at Earth surface. The general formula is $s = v_0t - {1\over2}gt^2$, and ${1\over2}g$ just happens to be about 16 if measured in units of $\mbox{ft/s}^2$.

Comment: What is the leading term of $s(t)$ if the time unit is minutes? Since the gravitational acceleration is $\approx 32 ft/sec^2$: $$\begin{align} s = -\frac{gt^2}{2} &= -\frac{16 ft}{sec^2}(t\;sec)^2 \\ &= \frac{16\,ft}{(min/60)^2}\left(t\frac{min}{60}\right)^2 = -16(60^2) \tau^2, \end{align}$$ where $\tau=t/60$ is the time in minutes. Now, redefine $\tau$ as $t$, then  $$ s(t) = -16\cdot 60^2 t^2 = -240^2t^2$$ where $t$ is in minutes.  Thus, the original form $s(t) = -16t^2$ must mean the time $t$ is in seconds.